# Multilevel dropdown menu. How get original state?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

This menu replace parent menu item.
Help get original state if press button Menu.
Try $('.navbar-dropdown).next('.navbar-dropdown-menu:first-child').clone(), but can`t replace when click button.

```js
$(function () {
$(document).on("click",  function (e) {
  var target = $(e.target);
  
  if (!(target).is('.navbar-dropdown-menu')) {
    $('.navbar-dropdown-content').hide();
  }
});
  
$('.navbar-dropdown-menu').on("click", function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent('.navbar-dropdown-content').replaceWith($(this).next('.navbar-dropdown-content').toggle());
 
  });
});
```

```css
.navbar-dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: gray;
}
.navbar-dropdown-content a {
  display: block;
  padding: .5em 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="navbar-dropdown">
 <button class="navbar-dropdown-menu" type="button">Menu</button>
 <div class="navbar-dropdown-content">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-dropdown-menu">1 item</a>
        <div class="navbar-dropdown-content">
          <a href="#" class="navbar-dropdown-menu">1.1 item</a>
            <div class="navbar-dropdown-content">
              <a href="#" class="navbar-dropdown-menu">1.1.1 item</a>
              <a href="#" class="navbar-dropdown-menu">1.1.2 item</a>
              <a href="#" class="navbar-dropdown-menu">1.1.3 item</a>
            </div>
          <a href="#" class="navbar-dropdown-menu">1.2 item</a>
        </div>
      <a href="#" class="navbar-dropdown-menu">2 item</a>
        <div class="navbar-dropdown-content">
          <a href="#" class="navbar-dropdown-menu">2.1 item</a>
          <a href="#" class="navbar-dropdown-menu">2.2 item</a>
          <a href="#" class="navbar-dropdown-menu">2.3 item</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I try save var original = $('.navbar-dropdown).next('.navbar-dropdown-menu:first-child').clone(); and replaceWith when click on $(this).(':button'). But after that even button not show .drop-down-content.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a `hidden` `input` into the HTML where the original state would be stored and read it from there and reuse it. Alternatively you could pass the original state as a JSON value to your Javascript code.